# Intersection observer using framer-motion

Tags: next.js, framer-motion

how to detect if the top of element is reached on the top of viewport screen using framer-motion? I don't know how to use the margin option of inView, can't find any tutorial on yt

Using the margin option of inView of framer-motion

Comment: Your question seems to be a [xy](https://xyproblem.info/) problem. provide some code that I can run and help you further.

Comment: Here's the screenshot of my code and the chrome dev tool: ibb.co/1GLvTmf as you can see on the right image where's the chrome dev tool my element with a white background color is not fully view on my viewport screen

Comment: can you paste code here?

Comment: `  useEffect(() => {
    const whyChooseSection = document.getElementById(
      'why-choose'
    ) as HTMLElement
    inView(whyChooseSection, () => {
      console.log('Element is on viewport')

      return () => console.log('Element is not on viewport')
    })
  }, [])`

Comment: as you can see I use getElementById because the element that I am tracking of the viewport is in other component

Comment: paste code in your question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useInView` hook from framer-motion

if you look at the params it accepts we can pass `root`, `amount`, `once` and also `margin`

> root: RefObject
> By default, useInView will track the visibility of an element as it enters/leaves the window viewport. Set root to be the ref of a scrollable parent, and it'll use that element to be the viewport instead.

> amount: "some" | "all" | number
> The amount of an element that needs to enter the viewport for useInView to return true.

> margin: string
> One or more margins to apply to the root element or window viewport. This can extend or contract the point at which the element is considered inside the viewport.
> Margins must be defined as px or %.

> once: boolean
> By setting once: true, once an element is in view, useInView will stop observing the element and always return true.

[image]

```js
import { useInView } from 'framer-motion'

const component = () => {
   const ref = useRef(null)
   const isInView = useInView(ref, {
      margin: "0px 100px -50px 0px"
      // pass other options if needed
   })

   return <div ref={ref}>{/* content */}</div>
};
```

[check more at docs](https://www.framer.com/motion/use-in-view/)

Comment: I know how to use inView and useInView but I don't understand how can I setup the option to detect the element when it reached on the top of viewport screen, what I want is detect when my element viewport height is 100% on my viewport screen

Comment: I think you need to play with the `amount` param. try setting it to `'all'` or `'some'` and see what suits best for you.

Comment: setting it to 'all' nothing happen, it can't detect the element if it is on the viewport, but the 'some' is like the default of behavior like when the element is on the viewport it's detecting already, what I want is if the whole element example my element have a 100vh size of height when that whole size element is on the whole size of viewport screen it will detect only

Comment: @IvanGregorTabalno you can also set the percentage from 0 to 1 in `amount` . if it still not working then share you code here.

Comment: Here's the screenshot of my code and the chrome dev tool:

https://ibb.co/1GLvTmf

as you can see on the right image where's the chrome dev tool my element with a white background color is not fully view on my viewport screen

Comment: @IvanGregorTabalno in your code you're not using `useInView` hook!

Comment: I think it's the same with inView, the difference only is inView can access of document.getElementById(), in useInView only refObject, if you check on the documentation they have the same of options, I want use "inView" because I want to access globally the element of I want to detect the viewport

Comment: i will recommend using `useInView` also you are not passing any option to inView. consider pasting you code in question so i can edit my answer.

Comment: I removed the option because there's no changes at all sir, my target element is in other component so that's why I used `inView` to target that element using `getElementById`